# How to connect to queues hosted on IBM MQ from Liberty application client (client.xml)?

Tags: java, client, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty, mq

I am pretty new for Liberty and please forgive me if my questions are very basic.

We have a standalone application (has a client module jar inside an Ear) where we post messages to queues in IBM MQ. 
We are planning to run the appplication in a Liberty Application Client container.

I tried describing the connection factory in client.xml, but its failing.

In the client.xml, for creating the MQ Connection factory we made the below changes.
1) Added the feature 
    javaeeClient-7.0
    wmqJmsClient-2.0
2) Specified the location of the IBM MQ Resource Adapter 
    .
3) Added the connection factory definitions.

```
<feature>javaeeClient-7.0</feature>
<feature>wmqJmsClient-2.0</feature>

<variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location" value="/path/to/wmq/rar/wmq.jmsra.rar"/>.

<jmsConnectionFactory jndiName="jms/wmqCF" connectionManagerRef="ConMgr6">
     <properties.wmqJms 
        transportType="CLIENT"
        hostName="localhost" 
        port="1414"
        channel="SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN"
        queueManager="QM1"/>
</jmsConnectionFactory>
<connectionManager id="ConMgr6" maxPoolSize="2"/>

<jmsQueue id="jms/queue1" jndiName="jms/wmqQ1">
     <properties.wmqJms 
        baseQueueName="MDBQ" 
        baseQueueManagerName="QM1"/>
</jmsQueue>
```

But when we run the client, we get the below error and the MQ Connection Factory lookup fails.

[ERROR] CWWKF0040E: The wmqJmsClient-2.0 feature that is specified in the client.xml file only supports server process types which will result in this feature not being run by the client process.
.
.
.
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'prvdCorrspndncServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jmsTemplate'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [config/mq.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mqConnectionFactory' while setting bean property 'connectionFactory'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mqConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [config/mq.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Intermediate context does not exist: jms/wmqCF

The same MQ configuration works for a different web application which is deployed in a Liberty Server and which uses server.xml.

Please help me understand how to create MQ connection factory to access the queues hosted on IBM MQ from a Liberty application client container (client.xml).

Comment: Can you say a little bit about why you need it in client.xml instead of server.xml? You say server.xml works, and the error message says that you cannot use wmqJmsClient-2.0 feature in client.xml

Comment: hi @Morag Hughson, we have to execute the application as a batch job. Our application has a main class. When the batch job executes, we will launch the main class using the client tool.